# Promove animation on HOVER - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, hover

I'd like to know some ways to animate icon on HOVER.. I'd like them to work like animated gifs...

Here is an example:
[TRASK INDUSTRIES LEFT MENU](http://www.trask-industries.com/)

When you hover icons on the left menu they get an animation!
I google unsuccessfully for a solution...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you referenced is using sprite sheets for animation. Essentially a sprite sheet is just an image that contains frames for an entire animation. When displayed, you crop the image to match the dimensions of a single frame and adjust the position of the image to move to different frames.

Here are some jQuery plugins to help you get started.

- [Spritely](http://spritely.net/)
- [SpriteSpin](http://spritespin.ginie.eu/)